# Change htaccess path?

Tags: .htaccess

This code works. What it does is rewrite's a subdomain so a specific directory will display. Basically it enables wildcard domains to exist.

Currently it does this.

`bob.domain.com` goes to `public_html/-bob`

I would like it to go to `public_html/__sites/-bob`. I tried the code below at the bottom but didn't have any joy. Help would be appreciated.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/-
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\./]+)
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/-%1 -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ -%1/$1 [L]
```

However it doesn't do what I want it to do.

Instead of it redirecting to `root/-directory`

I want it to redirect to `root/__sites/-directory`

I have tried this but I get a server error

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/-
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\./]+)
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/__sites/-%1 -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ __sites/-%1/$1 [L]
```

How do I tweak this code to get it working?

Comment: Please provide 1 or better 2 URL examples (from URL => to URL) -- it's much more easier to work with URLs and build my own rules rather than trying to figure out what this code supposed to do without having any clues on URLs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand you having 500 Internal Server Error. If you check your error log, there will be detailed explanation on the reason that caused it. I'm pretty sure it will be "Number of iterations exceeded" or something like that.

Considering my assumption is correct, this will be the correct rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/__sites/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\./]+)
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/__sites/-%1 -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ __sites/-%1/$1 [L]
```

The error caused by the fact that rewrite is not stopped when you specify the `[L]` flag -- it only goes to next iteration .. where your current rule will be executed again .. and again.

You have updated destination path from `public_html/-bob` to `public_html/__sites/-bob` .. but forgot to update the very first condition: should be `%{REQUEST_URI} !^/__sites/`.